# How to recursively render YAML using Jinja2?

Tags: recursion, yaml, jinja2

I have a YAML file with a structure that is not fixed (ex: the restaurant has attribute name and attribute food depending on the country, while the shop is only per country).
I would like to transform this YAML to get values for France only
ex:

```
myyaml:
  restaurant:
    name: "resto"
    food:
      italy: "pizza"
      japan: "sushi"
      france: "cheese"

  shop:
    italy: "Roma"
    japan: "Tokyo"
    France: "Paris"
```

for France I would have:

```
myyaml:
  restaurant:
    name: "resto"
    food: "cheese"

  shop: "Paris"
```

For this I would like to make a jinja2 template that would recursively parse the content of my YAML file and render it with the same structure but selecting only the values for "France".

Comment: Before you'll make the final decision regarding how to do what you want read this discussion: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/919

Comment: Jinja is not a good tool for YAML transformation. You'd be far better off with e.g. loading the YAML with Python, transforming the loaded structure and writing out the result as YAML.